# Control over LazyLoading children collection (Entity framework Code-First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

We have 3 tables `Teachers`, `Students`, `StudentFriendlyNames`. `Teachers` has 1 to many relation with `Students` like:

```
public Teacher
{
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public Student
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public string DisplayName { get; set; }
   ...

   public int TeacherId { get; set; }
   public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public StudentFriendlyNames
{ 
   public string OriginalName { get; set; }
   public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This table contains optional friendly name mappings between `Students` and `StudentFriendlyNames`.

What I'm looking for is whenever I do `teacher.Students.First().DisplayName` it should return `IsNULL(studentFriendlyName.FriendlyName, student.OriginalName)`

One possibility is: Whenever I do `teacher.Students` it returns all the students associated with the teacher (EF does this automatically for you). Here EF plays a role in populating the child entities, I want a control over it such that `DisplayName` is automatically populated. I will do the Join with `StudentFriendlyNames`, SQL equivalent would be like:

`SELECT std.*, ISNULL(sfn.FriendlyName, std.Name) AS DisplayName FROM Students std LEFT JOIN StudentFriendlyNames sfn ON std.Name = sfn.OriginalName AND sfn.IsActive = 1`

Of course on the other hand I could write `GetStudents` that does all what I want but I want to avoid that. `Teacher` object is being passed to different views (MVC view) and doing `Model.Students` inside the view hits the database. I do not want to pass both Teacher and associated Students to the views.

P.S. I can not create a simple relationship between `Students.Name` and `StudentFriendlyNames.OriginalName` as there is one additional table in between that I have not included for brevity.